# Get stuck in a loop while returning multiple arrays from a local function?

Tags: arrays, matlab, function, while-loop

I have to find the minimum and maximum angle of a catapult's trajectory that will make it over a wall. I have a local function that includes the motion equations and returns the distance at which the object lands, an array of x values, an array of y values, and the number of x and y values based on an input of lots of conditions called anglesfunction. In the main function, I tried to call it multiple times in a loop but it must be an infinite loop because I have to quit the program. It always quits on the same line, which is:

```
[temp(p), a, b, c(p)] = anglefunction(v0, w, m, d, h, dw, theta2(p), k);
```

I have it commented out right now, but I tried to do a similar thing later to do bisection and it stops at the same point there too. Here's my full code, `g` is gravity and is the only thing I am passing in to the main function.

```
function [mid] = longassignment3(g)
v0 = 40;
w = 5;
m = 10;
d = 50;
h = 5;
dw = 30;
theta1 = 38;
k = .05;
n = 1;
%hold on
%grid on
A = 0:.01:h;
%plot(dw, A, 'r', 'linewidth',2)
%plot(d, 0, 'linewidth', 2)
[distance, x, y, z] = anglefunction(v0, w, m, d, h, dw, theta1, k);  %should take out     eventually
%plot(x,y);
min = 0;
max = 0;
q = 1;
tol = .3;
tester = 2;
theta2 = 0:.01:90;
p = 1;
dt = 1e-3;
num = 1;
[temp(p), a, b, c(p)] = anglefunction(v0, w, m, d, h, dw, theta2(p), k);  %for p=1
while theta2(p) < 90
  p = p + 1;    %p becomes 2
  [temp(p), a, b, c(p)] = anglefunction(v0, w, m, d, h, dw, theta2(p), k);   %for p=2 the     first time
  B = size(a);
  while q <= B(2);
      if a(q) >= dw & a(q) <= (dw+tol)
          num = q;
      end
      q = q + 1;
  end
  if b(num) >= (h - tol) || b(num) <= (h+tol)  %if it hits wall
  min = 0;
  max = 0;
  else                                         %does not hit the wall
      if temp(p)<temp(p-1)
          min = theta2(p);                     %not assigning max and min
     elseif temp(p)>temp(p-1)
          max = theta2(p);
      end
  end
end
%min
%max
%distance = 0;
%q = 1;
%min = 26;
%max = 45;
%u = 1;
%done = 1;
%while done ~= 0
%    total = min + max;
%    mid = total/2;
%    [distance(u), a, b, c(u)] = anglefunction(v0, w, m, d, h, dw, mid, k);
%    if distance(u) < d
%        max = mid;
%    elseif distance(u) > d
%        min = mid;
%    elseif distance(u) >= d-tol | distance(u) <= d+tol
%        done = 0;
%    end
%    u = u + 1;
%end
end
if true
function [dist, x, y, n] = anglefunction(v0, w, m, d, h, dw, theta1, k)
n = 1;
g = 9.81;
%hold on
%grid on
A = 0:.01:h;
clear vx vy x y
%plot(dw, A, 'r', 'linewidth',2)
%plot(d, 0, 'linewidth', 2)
x(n) = 0;
y(n) = 0;
dvx = 0;
dvy = 0;
dt = 1e-3;
vx(n) = (v0)*(cos(theta1*pi/180));
vy(n) = (v0)*(sin(theta1*pi/180));  
while y(n)>=0 && x(n)>=0
  veff(n) = sqrt((vx(n) - w)^2 + (vy(n))^2);  
  dvx(n) = -k*veff(n)*(vx(n) - w)*dt/m;   
  dvy(n) = (-k*veff(n)*vy(n)/m-g)*dt;   
  vx(n+1) = vx(n) + (dvx(n));
  vy(n+1) = vy(n) + (dvy(n));
  x(n+1) = x(n) + (vx(n))*dt; 
  y(n+1) = y(n) + (vy(n))*dt; 
  n = n +1 ;
end
dist = x(n);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In the commented out while loop, max & min both become equal to 45 after a couple of iterations. This makes 'mid' equal to 45 as well, and so there is no change in the parameters you're passing into anglefunction each iteration. Therefore, there's no way that the 'done=0' condition can be reached and the while loop goes on forever.